# BASH script running two commands

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to adapt a script to run an extra command.

my original script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
UTIL=/opt/dcm4che-5.11.0/bin
INPUT=/opt/notes/cs1fill/2017/missing_cs1
suid=/opt/notes/cs1fill/2017/0020000D/suid.txt
cnt=0
START=1
count=$START
END=25000
awk -v S=$START -v E=$END 'NR>=S&&NR<=E {print $1}' $INPUT  | while read input1  #starting at a certain row
do
 echo "Row $count" | tee -a rowcount25k.txt
 ((cnt++))
 echo "Moving :" ${input1}
 $UTIL/findscu -c STORESCP@10.0.0.1:104 -m 00080050=${input1} -r0020000D --out-dir /opt/notes/cs1fill/2017/0020000D --out-file suid.txt
 $UTIL/movescu -c STORESCP@10.0.0.1:104 -m 0020000D=${suid1} --dest cs1FIR
  ((count++))
   if (( cnt == 50 )); then
    echo "Sleeping for 5 Seconds on $(date), I have moved $count exams"
    sleep 5
    cnt=0
   fi
exec 0<$3 #Restore old stdin.
done
echo "Counter:" $((count-START)) # Show moved items
```

The first command will read from input1 (a list of numbers with one column) and will write to a file named 'suid.txt'.

The 2nd command will read from the file 'suid.txt' to perform the last task.

My problem is that the first command that runs 'findscu' will overwrite the 'suid.txt' instead of adding to it, so I need the 2nd command to finish its task and then go back to the 1st command until it is finished reading from 'input1'.

any help with be appreciated

Comment: Consider building a [mcve] that isolates the specific issue you want assistance in solving, outside the scope of the larger script. Doing that well will result in a script others can run to see your problem (and to test whether their proposed answers fix that problem), even if they *don't* have `findscu`, `movescu`, a `/opt/notes` directory, or any of the other local dependencies.

Comment: (You might also fix the bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ identifies in your script before asking questions about it here).

Answer (score 0):

This is about findscu. This program has default overwrite file instead of add to end of file. This is normal for all programs what have possibly to redirect output to file.

For example tee has special parameter, to not overwrite:

```
-a      Append the output to the files rather than overwriting them.
```

I don't know this program, but maybe if you don't give --out-directory and --out-file paramaters then output is to stdout? Try this:

```
$UTIL/findscu -c STORESCP@10.0.0.1:104 -m 00080050=${input1} >> /opt/notes/cs1fill/2017/0020000D/suid.txt
```